# Ajax loading graphic

Tags: javascript, ajax, gif

So I'm no JavaScript genius, but I can follow a tutorial just fine. I've got my Ajax JavaScript request. How do I make it so that I can make a .gif animation show while the information is being requested? Here's the code:

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('confirm');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var queryString = "?number=" + number + "&message=" + message;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "sms.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

The name of the GIF file is ajax-loader.gif.

I know this can be done easily with jQuery, but I can only use straight, original JavaScript code for this, not extra libraries.

Comment: @icktoofay As I said, used a tutorial. He must've used the same one.

Comment: I know, I was just saying it was interesting how one tutorial can get multiple questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the AJAX request, add an `img` element:

```
var image=document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src', 'ajax-loader.gif');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(image);
```

When the AJAX request is done, remove it. (this code assumes `image` is still in scope)

```
image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
```

Comment: So does this put the image into a body div?

Comment: It will put it into the `body`. There is no `div` involved.

Comment: Just... anywhere in the body?

Comment: At the end of the `body`. You can change it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would avoid using this methodology for your XHR requests.  I would use jQuery or some other framework.  They provide you many more tested options that you can code yourself in any reasonable amount of time.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ is a good place to start.  You can use the beforeSend and the afterSend events.